# File upload with Backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js in a Rails app and I need to do file uploads as part of one of the Backbone models.

I don't believe Backbone allows for multi-part file upload out of the box. Has anyone managed to get it working via some plugin or with another external lib? How can I extend Backbone.js to support this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering my own question after few months of trial using different methods. My solution is the following (with Rails).

For any form that requires file upload I would set `data-remote="true"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and include [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) and [jquery.iframe-transport.js](https://github.com/cmlenz/jquery-iframe-transport/blob/master/jquery.iframe-transport.js).

Setting `data-remote="true"` with [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) allows me to bind to `ajax:success` and create the Backbone.js model on success.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/posts.js" method="post" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="post[message]" />
  <input type="file" name="post[file]" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

*You should obviously bind `ajax:error` to handle error cases.*

*For me, the data is sanitized in the `ActiveRecord` model, so don't have to worry too much about the `eval` statement.*

```
$('form').bind('ajax:success', function(event, data) {
  new Model(eval(data)); // Your newly created Backbone.js model
});
```

**Rails Controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def create
    @post = Post.create(params[:post])
    respond_with @post
  end
end
```

**Rails View (create.js.haml):**

*Using the [remotipart](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart) gem.*

*This will handle the case when the form does file uploads with `enctype` being set, and when it doesn't.*

*You could choose to call `sanitize` on your response here.*

```
= remotipart_response do
  - if remotipart_submitted?
    = "eval(#{Yajl::Encoder.encode(@post)});"
  - else
    =raw "eval(#{Yajl::Encoder.encode(@post)});"
```

Comment: Neat. Two questions though. In your controller, did you intend to do `Post.new(params[:post])` or did you actually mean `Post.create(params[:post])`? And second, where would you place the `$('form').bind('ajax:success')` callback, in a Backbone.View class for the given form? Thanks!

Comment: Great catch, typo on my part. It should be `Post.create`. I would place $('form').bind('ajax:success') in my Backbone view that renders the form.

Comment: Add data-type="json" to the form and you can remove the view.

Comment: As @Maletor pointed out, you can simply return JSON. I've had trouble with this approach with earlier versions of remotipart but it seems to work well now.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the [jquery.iframe.transport](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/) plugin. If you're using rails 3, you can use [remotipart](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart) instead (it bundles the iframe.transport plugin), which hooks into rails's ujs driver to automatically add support for file upload in ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I ended up using exactly what you described a while back but didn't get around to updating this question.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this one.

As mentioned in previous answers, a multipart/form-data request can be executed via `jQuery.ajax`:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var input = document.getElementById('file');

formData.append('file', input.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'path/to/upload/endpoint'
  type:'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
});
```

It is also important to note that, out-of-the-box, `Backbone.sync` will merge any options via `model.save(null, { /* options here */ })` with the `$.ajax` instructions.

Your save procedure would look something like:

```
var model = new Model({
  key: 'value'
});
var input = document.getElementById('file');
var formData = new FormData();

_.each(model.keys(), function (key) { // Append your attributes
  formData.append(key, model.get(key));
});

formData.append('file', input.files[0]); // Append your file

model.save(null, {
  data: formData, 
  processData: false,
  contentType: false 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how backbone works. Backbone is an MVC library for javascript, not a web server.  File uploads are negotiated between the clients browser and your server. Backbone is just the middle layer that helps you organize and present data in an easy, convenient manner.

That being said, what you need to do to associate a file with your model is 1) handle the upload with rails and then 2) store the file name and location in a string within your model.

So here's the file uploading part:

> http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent

Once you get back the list_item object, you would just create a new field in your model and store `list_item.filename` and `asset_path(list_item)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, here is a link to a similar SO question for Django http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092596/backbone-js-link-file-to-model

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to break backward compatibility, you can take advantage of [XHR2 and FormData](http://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest%202)

It's simple as that:

```
var data = new FormData( $('form.someForm').get(0) );
$.ajax('http://*****.com', {
  type:'POST',
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false // it automaticly sets multipart/form-data; boundary=...
});
```